# Average integration is increasing with measure

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality, holder-inequality

I was studying Evans' PDE, Morrey's Inequality. A step confused me: Is it correct that there is a constant depending only on $n$ so that  $ \frac{\int_U f}{|U|}\leq C\frac{\int_V f}{|V|}$ if $U\subset V\subset \mathbb R^n$ and $f\geq 0$ ? One may assume  U,V bounded and open. I had tried some ways such as "$\int_V f\cdot(|V|1_{\chi_U}) \underset{?}{\leq} |U| \int_V f $" by  Holder's inequality but failed. Can anyone tell the trick ?

Comment: Just look at the particular case: Let $V=\{0,1\}$, $U=\{0\}$, $f(0)=2$, $f(1)=-2$ and the measure the counting measure. Then $\int_Uf/|U|=2/1=2$, while $\int_Vf/|V|=(2-2)/2=0$. The book probably has additional conditions that one needs to use.

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistake about the statement.

Comment: Still not enough. I changed a little bit the example to falsify the new statement too.

Comment: Which page is it?

Comment: If it is the step in the third block of formulas on page 267, then what is being done is not that. They are just using the monotonicity of the integral $\int_Af\leq \int_Bf$, when $f\geq0$ and $A\subset B$.

Comment: page 268 , formula (25) of Theorem 4.

Comment: Actually, it find it is quite easy  : $\int_U f / |U| \leq \int_V f/|U| \leq C|U|/|V| \int_V f/|U|$. Since the shapes of $U$ and $V$ in the case is fixed, we can make $C$ so large that 
$C|U|/|V|>1$

Comment: Yes, in that one it is just a matter of the $W$ there being the union of two balls and using monotonicity of the integral.